# Python problem in multiplying the elements in lists

Tags: python, list

I am just learning python and I encountered a problem in the code. the problem is that when I try to multiply the elements of the lists by the code:-

```
r = [1,2,3,4,5]
total_m_1 = 1
for elemants_1 in r:
    total_m_1 = total_m_1 * elemants_1
    print(total_m_1)
```

Output :

```
2
6
24
120
```

... but I only want the final result, i.e. 120.

Comment: Move the `print` out of the `for` loop. Voting to close for minor typo.

Comment: Unindent the final print statement.

Comment: untab your final print statement to bring it out of the loop.

Comment: Note that you are only reimplementing `math.factorial`

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Place the `print` statement *after* the loop:

```
r = [1,2,3,4,5]
total_m_1 = 1
for elemants_1 in r:
    total_m_1 = total_m_1 * elemants_1

print(total_m_1)
```

This way, it will print only once, after all of the calculations are finished.

Answer (score 0):

No need to shout, friend.

```
r = [1,2,3,4,5]
total_m_1 = 1
for elemants_1 in r:
    total_m_1 = total_m_1 * elemants_1
print(total_m_1)
```

Answer (score 0):

You have given an extra indentation to your print statement which is printing intermediate results

```
r = [1,2,3,4,5]
total_m_1 = 1
for elemants_1 in r:
    total_m_1 = total_m_1 * elemants_1

print(total_m_1)
```

As you are learning thought it might be useful to give more options
Using numpy

```
import numpy as np
np.prod(r)
```

Using toolz

```
from toolz import accumulate
from operator import mul
r = [1,2,3,4,5]
list(accumulate(mul,r))[-1]
```